# Java save file from url to web directory

Tags: java

I need to save url file (for example http://page.com/list.html) to my "web/lists" directory to be accessible for other internet users (I use Netbeans and it created build, dist, nbproject, src, web and test directories).

This is my code (I use org.apache.commons.io) - I have it in ordinary java class, so I cannot use request.getRealPath() which is depricated anyway.

```
try {
        URL dl = new URL("http://page.com/list.html");
        File fl = new File("dont/know/what/directory/here/lists/2017-06-01-list.html");

        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(dl, fl, 600000, 600000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("nok");
    }
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much

Comment: In what way is this failing?  Is there an error?  Unexpected result?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know in which constant there is path to "web directory". It is in getServletContext().getRealPath(), but I cannot use this in simple java class.

Comment: In a simple way: I need a function which download the file http://page.com/list.html and save it to http://mywebsite.com/2017-06-01.html. Thats all. I don't know what to use as am argumnet of File constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `user.dir` property to get the current directory and append the path of destination directory with `File.separator`. This is what the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) says:

> "user.dir" : User working directory

Another option is to use `getRealPath()` method of `ServletContext` (javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String))) and build the relative path using this, e.g.:

```
String scPath = getServletContext().getRealPath();
String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Comment: getServletContext().getRealPath() is working if I put the code to .jsp file. But I need to use it in ordinary Java class. propeties user.dir and user.home don't lead to my project web directory, but to apache instalation on another disc :(

Comment: Yes, `user.dir` will return the directory where your application is deployed. For `realPath`, can you not pass it as an argument to that class method (probably via `request attribute`)? Hard coding paths inside methods is not a good practice anyway.